# How to install SDL?

Tags: installation, mingw, notepad++, sdl

I would like to use SDL in my programs, but I can't seem to get it working. I looked around the internet for answer, but all of them were applicable to some IDE, and those are of no help in my case as I am using Notepad++ to edit my code and compile my code using minGW through CMD.
Would someone be nice enough to provide specific steps to install SDL, or should I just give up my way of coding and switch to using IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDL documentation on their [website](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation) brings you to the [pre-compiled libraries](https://buildbot.libsdl.org/sdl-builds/sdl-visualstudio/?C=M;O=D), on which you find the zip file (you probably can take the newest) that contains the lib files and headers.

Extract the zip file and you get a directory called `SDL`. Now you can compile your code with MingW linking the libraries:

```
g++ -I%PROJPATH%/SDL/include -L%PROJPATH%/SDL/lib/win32 -lSDL2 -o yourprog yourcode.cpp
```

where `%PROJPATH%` is your project path that includes the `SDL` directory.

For compiling with external headers and libraries also see:

- [HOWTO Specify the Header File Include Path for use with MinGW Compilers.](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/IncludePathHOWTO)
- [HOWTO Specify the Location of Libraries for use with MinGW.](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Specify_the_Location_of_Libraries_for_use_with_MinGW)